# How to funnel an API call to a specific service fabric node

Tags: websocket, architecture, azure-service-fabric

I have exposed a websocket enabled service endpoint through Azure Application Gateway and the service is hosted on azure service fabric. Client initiates a websocket connection with my endpoint and is able to exchange data. During certain message flows, my Web Socket enabled service calls other services hosted on the service fabric using azure service bus. These are handled in a completely async manner. Once the other services finish processing, they post a message to the service bus which my WebSocket service reads back.
The problem I am having is to route the messages back to the right service fabric node so that it can be pushed back to the client at the other end of the WebSocket connection

In the picture below, you can imagine each node containing multiple services including the web socket enabled service. Once the Websocket service posts a message to the service bus, the downstream services start processing and finally they post a message back to the service bus which the websocket service reads back. Here a random node will pick up the message and it might not have the relevent websocket connection to push the processed data back
[Sample Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SorIx.png)

I have looked at redis pubsub model and it looks like I have to maintain last message processed on the nodes. It also means, every node on the cluster will need to read the message and discard it if they don't have the websocket connection with the client. I am looking for any suggested design models for this kind of problem

Comment: Did you settle on a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry for a late response.. I had put this work on hold due to some other commitments. I am leaning towards using a Reliable Service Partitioning to route the call to the same node. I  will use a common key in the calls that need to go on to the same partition.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I finally implemented it using azure service bus sessions to get an exclusive lock to a session

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar scenario and didn't like the idea of using a new external service (Redis/SQL Server) as a backplane that would simply duplicate each message/event across all nodes.

The solution I settled on was to lean on a property of actor proxies, using actor events to call-back to a **specific instance** of a stateless service. Creating an actor service to act as a pub/sub backplane.

The solution is summarised in [this blog post](https://undocumented.dev/signalr-scaleout-using-service-fabric-actor-events/) and [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/olivergrimes/servicefabric-topicactor-signalr).  It's worth pointing out that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-events) states actor events are *best effort*.  This hasn't really been an issue when the application is running as normal, I presume that during a deployment or failover, some events may get lost, however this could be mitigated with additional work.

It's also worth noting that your load balancing rules should maintain sticky connections between clients and back-end instances.  You could create separate rules for websockets if you only wanted this to apply to them and not your regular HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. This looks to be a very good alternative to pubsub via external service.. I will try this out